# Knockout JS Having models inside multiple partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, knockout.js, partial-views, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I am loading 4 partial views in a page. The main page that contains all the partial views in separate divs and each partial view has its own knockout model. The issue that I am having is that the individual knockout models cannot bind values for text fields and what not.

I would like to keep the pages separate so the main page is not so cluttered and tightly coupled to the partial views. This is essentially a summary of these 4 pages that were previously completed.

It seems that I cannot pull the knockout models out since they need information from the controller to populate the partial view and I do not want to pull the partial views into this page.

Essentially I want to load partial views with their own knockout models and have desired functionality.

Comment: Can you show us the code for what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like in your case, you will want to use the second argument to `ko.applyBindings`.

The second argument allows you to pass a DOM element that you want to use as the root element to bind against.

So, if you loaded your partial views into elements like:

```
<div id="one">
...
</div>
<div id="two">
....
</div>
```

You can bind different view models to each container like:

```
ko.applyBindings(oneModel, document.getElementById("one"));

ko.applyBindings(twoModel, document.getElementById("two"));
```

Comment: I do that already and it still doesn't get me what I need which is being able to apply bindings in the partial views. So to be clear, I call ko.applybindings in my partial views because they contain their models.

Comment: So, are you calling ko.applyBindings with no second argument after the content from the partial view has been populated (or inline as part of the partial)?.  If you are already properly binding the individual containers, then you will likely need to share more code to determine why your binding is failing.

Comment: Im using the second argument with each model in their own partial. I think the solution is to have one big model that has objects that represent the partials and then when the big model is created i use ajax to get the paritals and load it into their divs and then reference the partials through the objects in the big model

Comment: That is an option (using the `with` binding then on the containers is very helpful), but applying bindings to each container is also supported.  I was still not quite clear on what problem that you were seeing.  Are there errors in the console?  Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

In each partial view, place some JavaScript at the very bottom of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings(viewModelObject, document.getElementById("someDivId")); 
</script>
```

This will apply the bindings at the right time. Otherwise, due to the asynchronous way that the views load, the bindings will not work.

Note: viewModelObject should be defined in the main view, as well as the general ko include files.